# MATLAB How do I add surf function on my current program

Tags: matlab

Im not too familiar with Matlab but this is with regards to my project for school.

I currently have issues as im not familiar with Matlab and only just figured how the quiver3 function works. How can I add the `surf` functions or any other functions to help easily visualise this program I have? Thank you.

Im open to any possible suggestions. This code is to visualise the electric field of a dipole antenna.

```
I = 0.2;
k = 0.5;
r = 15; %radius
n = 0.1;
theta = 0;

x = linspace(-10000000,10000000,15);
y = linspace(-10000000,10000000,15);
z = linspace(-10000000,10000000,15);

[x,y,z] = meshgrid(x,y,z);

if (theta < 361)
    theta = theta + 1; %%to cover 360 degrees

    b = cos(pi/2 * cos(theta)) ./ sin(theta); %2nd half of eqn

    eX = 1i * n * b * (I * exp(1i * k * x)) ./ (2 * pi * x); %radius in x axis
    eY = 1i * n * b * (I * exp(1i * k * y)) ./ (2 * pi * y); %radius in y axis
    eZ = 1i * n * b * (I * exp(1i * k * z)) ./ (2 * pi * z); %radius in z axis
end

figure()
for i = 1:r
    quiver3(x,y,z,eX,eY,eZ,1.5)
end

xlabel('X Axis');
ylabel('Y Axis');
zlabel('Z Axis');
title('Test','color','r');
axis equal;
```

Comment: Did you post the whole code? A loop seems missing: `theta` is initialized to `0` but you test if it is `<361`: `theta`  You call `quiver` 15-times but nohing changes at each iteration

Comment: yeap the whole code is in there.. what should I add to further improve this code?